# npx: the shell-auto-fallback argument has been removed

Tags: shell, zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh, npx

I honestly don't remember what I last installed on my machine, I believe it was brewing gatsby-cli. Anyway, since yesterday morning my terminal has been giving me the following error when I open a new instance or reset the terminal (open a new tab, source ~/.zshrc, etc).

```
Last login: Tue Nov 17 10:40:14 on ttys000
npx: the --shell-auto-fallback argument has been removed.
See `npm help exec` for more information
```

It just loops that until I break the command with ^c, and even then the terminal is in basically a not valid state, it seems like the path hasn't fully loaded (i.e. commands in my .zshrc file, like alias commands, won't execute--command not found).

Note: I'm using iterm2.

Here is my zshrc:

```
# Enable Powerlevel10k instant prompt. Should stay close to the top of ~/.zshrc.
# Initialization code that may require console input (password prompts, [y/n]
# confirmations, etc.) must go above this block; everything else may go below.
if [[ -r "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh" ]]; then
  source "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh"
fi

# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="/Users/earlem3/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
# ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
source /usr/local/opt/powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme

# Set list of themes to pick from when loading at random
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random will cause zsh to load
# a theme from this variable instead of looking in $ZSH/themes/
# If set to an empty array, this variable will have no effect.
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion.
# Case-sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to automatically update without prompting.
DISABLE_UPDATE_PROMPT="true"

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in $ZSH/plugins/
# Custom plugins may be added to $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(alias-finder brew common-aliases copydir copyfile docker docker-compose dotenv encode64 extract git jira jsontools node npm npx osx urltools vi-mode vscode web-search z)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
  export EDITOR='code'
else
  export EDITOR='nano'
fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
alias code="code-insiders"
alias iboss="/Applications/Utilities/iboss.app/gen4agent/reconfigure.sh reload"

source ~/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh

# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.p10k.zsh.
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh

source /usr/local/share/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
source /usr/local/share/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh

# following 3 commands are all for history-substring-search
source /usr/local/share/zsh-history-substring-search/zsh-history-substring-search.zsh
bindkey '^[OA' history-substring-search-up
bindkey '^[OB' history-substring-search-down

#anyenv
eval "$(anyenv init -)"

#nodenv
eval "$(nodenv init -)"

# NPX auto-fallback
source <(npx --shell-auto-fallback zsh)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Per the [Readme for npx plugin in OhMyZsh github repo](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/npx#deprecation),

> Since `npm v7`, `npx` has been moved to `npm exec`. With the move, the
> `--shell-auto-fallback` argument for `npx` has been removed:
>
> `Shell fallback functionality is removed, as it is not advisable.`
>
> When using npm v7, you'll get this error:
>
> `npx: the --shell-auto-fallback argument has been removed`
>
> If you get this error, just disable the plugin by removing it from the
> plugins array in your zshrc file. This plugin will no longer be
> maintained and will be removed in the future, when the older npx
> versions are no longer available.

As suggested, try removing `npx` from the following line in your `.zshrc`

```
plugins=(alias-finder brew common-aliases copydir copyfile docker docker-compose dotenv encode64 extract git jira jsontools node npm npx osx urltools vi-mode vscode web-search z)
```

.. also remove the last two line in your `.zshrc`

```
# NPX auto-fallback
source <(npx --shell-auto-fallback zsh)
```

Comment: Removing `npx` from the plugins line fixed this issue for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Try removing the npx plugin from `plugins=(...)` in .zshrc. I had the same problem and that solved it for me.