# macOS: iTerm2: repetitive: "npx: --shell-auto-fallback removed"

Tags: zsh, macos-mojave, iterm2, npx

macOS **iTerm2** is stuck repetitively printing out errors, thereby this shell is inaccessible to correct any problems.

**Problem Details:**

I did a `brew cleanup` and something got messed up, and **iTerm2** is now repetitively displaying...

```
Last login: Sun Feb  7 19:27:56 on ttys000
npx: the --shell-auto-fallback argument has been removed.
See `npm help exec` for more information
npx: the --shell-auto-fallback argument has been removed.
See `npm help exec` for more information
npx: the --shell-auto-fallback argument has been removed.
See `npm help exec` for more information
***
```

**Environment Details:**

- Laptop is **macOS (Mojave 10.14.6)**
- Terminal is **iTerm2 3.2.9** app
- Code primarily in **node**
- Default shell is **zsh**.

**Resolution Attempts:**

I came across the recent StackOverflow: [npx: the shell-auto-fallback argument has been removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64914875/npx-the-shell-auto-fallback-argument-has-been-removed)

However, this will not help because I am unable to key in anything while this is perpetually printing.

I tried overriding shell in **iTerm2** to stop using **zsh** and instead use **bash**, but that did not help either:

[image]

**Help!**

I am out of ideas. **Any suggestions will be helpful. Thank you.**

Comment: Have you tried booting in safe mode ? support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try. Uncertain how to do that, but I will look that up.

Comment: Booted into Safe mode, iTerm2 still stuck in the repetitive error message.

Comment: @JeffTanner: I don't see how bash would end up using npx somewhere, unless you messed up your dot files. You could try to configure iTerm to use `bash -ilx` as shell, and analyse the trace. It should show you at which point `npx` is invoked.

Comment: Too much was messed up. Restored macOS and reinstalled everything node. Now things are good. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Too much was messed up.

- **Restored macOS**
- Reinstalled **brew**
- Reinstalled everything **zsh**
- Reinstalled everything **node**

Now everything is good.

**IMPORTANT:** Have a Time Machine backup, I did not. That would have saved me a lot of work